# How to PROPERLY remove xmln:xsi and xmlns:xsd from xml dictionary serialization

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, dictionary, xml-serialization

Question: 
I use a serializable dictionary class, found at 
http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx
, to serialize a dictionary.
It works fine with the example class below.

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ccl")> _
Public Class ccl
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("name")> _
    Public xx As String = ""

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("date")> _
    Public yy As String = ""


    '<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("adict")> _
    'Public ww As New SerializableDictionary(Of String, String)

End Class
```

But it adds a,

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance AND xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema?
```

to the  tag

Now I fixed it by changing the dictionary class to

```
       Dim ns As System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces()
        'Add an empty namespace and empty value
        ns.Add("", "")

        If True Then
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, ns)
        Else
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value)
        End If
```

which removes those attributes.

But that also means it does not write them if I specify them.
How can I add those two empty namespaces to the class using attributes ?

I changed it to

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ccl", Namespace:="")>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you rephrase a bit? I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use to serialize to my object o

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces XSN = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
XSN.Add("", "");
XmlWriterSettings XWS = new XmlWriterSettings();
XWS.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
StringBuilder XmlStr = new StringBuilder();
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
x.Serialize(XmlTextWriter.Create(XmlStr, XWS), o, XSN);
```

Comment: not OmitXmlDeclaration, just omit the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd attributes