# Get pure XML from Object

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have following code which converts Object into XML and it working fine.

```
    public static string ConvertObjectToXML(Object obj)
    {
        String XmlizedString = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xs = null;

            if (obj is DerivedClass2)
            {
                xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DerivedClass2));
            }

        TextWriter w = new StringWriter();
        //this.s = new XmlSerializer(this.type);
        xs.Serialize(w, notoficationOrder);
        w.Flush();
        //return w;
        XmlizedString = w.ToString();
        w.Close();
        return XmlizedString.Trim();
   }
```

And it gives following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>*   
<Obj xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <List>
        <!--...-->
    </List>
</Obj>
```

But I do not want XML which depicts  Xml Namespace xd etc. I need only pure Object output of as below

```
<Obj>
  <List>
     <!--...-->
  </List>
</Obj>
```

Thanks

Ocean

Comment: possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625927/omitting-all-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces-when-serializing-an-object-in-net

Comment: I can understand you want this, but there is a reason they exist. To avoid a crash when two elements have the same name, but are different objects.

Answer (score 1):

[How to PROPERLY remove xmln:xsi and xmlns:xsd from xml dictionary serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263824/how-to-properly-remove-xmlnxsi-and-xmlnsxsd-from-xml-dictionary-serialization)

This is VB .NET but the idea is the same.